# How do I count of how many documents the field x is empty inside a certian collection?

Tags: arangodb

I have problem. I have a collection `orders`. I want to check how many documents with the field `phone` are empty.

So how could I count of how many documents the field `phone` is empty inside the collection `orders`?

This my collection `orders`:

```py
[
{'_id': 'orders/213123',
 'contactEditor': {'name': 'Max Power',
  'phone': '1234567',
  'email': 'max@power.com'},
 'contactSoldToParty': {'name': 'Max Not',
  'phone': '123456789',
  'email': 'maxnot@power.com'},
 'isCompleteDelivery': False,
 'metaData': {'dataOriginSystem': 'Goods',
  'dataOriginWasCreatedTime': '10:12:12',},
 'orderDate': '2021-02-22',
 'orderDateBuyer': '2021-02-22',
},
{'_id': 'orders/12323',
 'contactEditor': {'name': 'Max Power2',
  'phone': '1234567',
  'email': 'max@power.com'},
 'contactSoldToParty': {'name': 'Max Not',
  'phone': '123456789',
  'email': 'maxnot@power.com'},
 'isCompleteDelivery': False,
 'metaData': {'dataOriginSystem': 'Goods',
  'dataOriginWasCreatedTime': '10:12:12',},
 'orderDate': '2021-02-22',
 'orderDateBuyer': '2021-02-22',
 },
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to `FILTER` for a value that is `null`...

```js
FOR o IN orders
    FILTER o.contactSoldToParty.phone == null
    RETURN o
```

But if you just want a simple count, then I would use `COLLECT` (see the [docs](https://www.arangodb.com/docs/3.9/aql/operations-collect.html))...

```js
FOR o IN orders
    COLLECT hasPhone = (o.contactSoldToParty.phone != null) WITH COUNT INTO total
    RETURN { hasPhone, total }
```

There are two caveats, both related to how your document is structured:

1. you may have to first check if the `contactSoldToParty` attribute exists (or use [nullish coalescing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator))
2. be sure that the `phone` attribute is indeed empty/missing/null - `null` is not the same as an empty string (`''`)